# Saving consumed data to database

Tags: spring-boot, rest, h2, consumer

I am having a problem with saving data from consumed API to database, so this is my model:

```java
@Entity
public class Beer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

Also in my Service I have:

```java
ResponseEntity<Beer> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
    "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers",
    Beer.class
);
```

Now I don't know how to use this to save data to database. Any ideas?

Comment: What's exactly what you don't know? You know how to use a repository#save?

Comment: Do I have to save "response" to the repository?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the entity `Bean` you have to use the `getBody()` method.

```java
ResponseEntity<Beer> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
    "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers",
    Beer.class
);
```

```java
Beer entity = response.getBody();
```

To save that entity, you should use the save method of the repository.

```
respository.saveAndFlush(entity);
```

In case you don't have the respository instance, you can autowire it like this:

```java
class Example {
    @Autowire RespositoryClassYouAlreadyHave respository;
}
```

You can learn more at this guide:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-save-saveandflush